# Plural to avoid specifics

Tags: plural-forms

Can you use plural nouns to avoid referring to specific nouns? Please see my example below:

> **Packages** will be delivered to **the customers** who have placed **the orders.**

If I write something like this, am I referring to general packages, customers, and orders? I'm not sure if I would want to use "the" since I don't want to refer to any specific packages/customers/orders. Is this sentence correct or is there some other way to express this kind of sentence?

EDIT:

Sorry, I must have been extremely unclear. Let me try this with a different example.

> You need to confirm **each order** with **the customer** who has placed **it**.

I want to generalize this sentence into a general instruction.

> You need to confirm **orders** with **customers** who have placed **them**.

If I write something like the sentence above, am I creating a generalized instruction that doesn't refer to any specific orders and customers?

Comment: Do you mean to say that each package will be delivered to the customer who ordered it, or are you trying to say something other than that?

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatically, OP's example wouldn't normally have *any* articles...

> Packages will be delivered to customers who have placed orders.

...but that would be a rather odd thing to say anyway, since it's blindingly obvious in any normal context. If we change it slightly to something the reader might actually need to be told...

> Delivery priority will be given to customers who have placed orders before 5 pm.

...then we *still* wouldn't normally include any articles. But optionally *those* (or much less often, *the*) might reasonably be added before *customers*. It wouldn't significantly affect the meaning, but some might feel it emphasises the difference between *those particular customers* and the ones who ordered late at night.

---

As to the *singular/plural* distinction, it's theoretically/grammatically possible to say, for example...

> Delivery priority will be given to a customer who has placed an order before 5 pm.

...but in practice native speakers would rarely do this for that exact meaning and construction.

Comment: Your last example hints at the possibility that of those customers who placed orders before 5, one will be singled out for delivery priority.

Comment: @jwpat: The merest "hint", I guess. But I suspect mainly that lucky customer is a figment of your febrile imagination. If he really existed, I think the company's copywriter would have probably written *...given to **one of the customers** who has...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Okay, I'm not sure if I'm getting it. Is it then possible to turn "Each order will be shipped to the customer who has placed it" into "Orders will be shipped to customers who have placed them"? Theoretically, I mean. I understand this is an awkward sentence but I'm trying to grasp this concept. Please advise!

Comment: @jess: I'm slightly struggling to understand why anyone would want/need to say *"Each order will be shipped to the customer who has placed it"* (who else would you ship it to?). But putting aside jwpat's slightly perverse/contrived interpretation above, idiomatically we can often use singular when we're actually talking about the general (i.e. - plural) case. Consider, for example, [the/a family that prays together stays together](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/family+that+prays+together+stays+together). That "really" means *families that pray together stay together*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Right, sorry, I understand that my example is awkward. But your example makes sense. So "you need to check each answer" is pretty much the same as "you need to check (the) answers", right? But then again, I think this is a bit awkward, too. I can't really come up with good examples!

Comment: @jess: I don't see anything "awkward" about *"you need to check each answer"* (or *"you need to check **every** answer"*). In most cases there would be no difference if you said *"you need to check [all] the answers"*. The only "awkward" version would be *"you need to check answers"* (and note that singular *"you need to check answer"* would ***never*** be acceptable to a native speaker).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If the customers are members of a common group, saying "each order will be shipped to the customer that placed it" will make it clear that the orders should be addressed individually; an alternative would be to throw all the orders in a box addressed to e.g. the leader of the group.  Note that using "each" implies individual addressing much more strongly than would "orders will be shipped to the customers who placed them".